# Trying to set Discord bot presence

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

ello, I am new to starting a discord bot project with the slash commands. I am trying to use some code from an old bot of mine to try and set the presence on my new bot. When launching, I get the console message and my bot goes online… status does not set.

The documentation I have been following:
[Discord Documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/getting-started)

Here is my code below:

botpresence.cjs

```
const {
  Discord,
  Client,
  Intents,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  ActivityType,
} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
  ],
});

module.exports.namedCjsExport = function namedCjsExport() {
  client.once("ready", () => {
    client.user.setPresence("Watching Dev", { type: "WATCHING" });
    setInterval(() => {
      client.user.setPresence("Watching Dev", { type: "WATCHING" });
    }, 60000);
  });
};

console.log("Bot is online!");

client.login(
  "TOKEN"
);
```

app.js

```
import defaultCjsExport, { namedCjsExport } from './botpresence.cjs';
namedCjsExport()
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import { InteractionType, InteractionResponseType } from "discord-interactions";
import {
  VerifyDiscordRequest,
  getRandomEmoji,
  DiscordRequest,
} from "./utils.js";

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.json({ verify: VerifyDiscordRequest(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY) }));


app.post("/interactions", async function (req, res) {
  const { type, id, data } = req.body;

  if (type === InteractionType.PING) {
    return res.send({ type: InteractionResponseType.PONG });
  }

  if (type === InteractionType.APPLICATION_COMMAND) {
    const { name } = data;

    if (name === "test") {
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          content: "Finally online and responding     " + getRandomEmoji(),
        },
      });
    }

    if (name === "test2") {
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          content: "Going in for a second command",
        },
      });
    }
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port", PORT);
});
```

It reads the bot is online in the console but does not show the status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [`setPresence()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) (or) `setActivity()` you need to provide a `PresenceData` for it.

For example if you want to se the presence for your bot you should do:

```js
client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'Watching Dev', type: 3 }], status: 'online');
```

More about the ActivityType you can find [from here](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType).

But you could find [`setActivity()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) better suited, and easier for yourself:

```js
client.user.setActivity('Watching Dev', { type: ActivityType.Watching });
```